# Is there an English word containing the vowels ɤ or ɐ, and if not, which similar-sounding vowels are there in English?

Tags: pronunciation, alphabet

I need examples for English words which contain the sounds ɤ (close-mid back unrounded vowel) and ɐ (schwa, an unstressed neutral vowel). But I am not sure if there are such words at all. If there aren't, I'd like examples for words which contain similar sounds. As I don't understand phonetics well, I can't think of such words by myself. My best guess is to use words like `duck`, which to me sound very similar, but are actually written with `ʌ`.

Some background details for the question: I want to explain (in chat) to an English speaker (who reads Cyrillic, but doesn't speak Bulgarian) how the letter `ъ` is pronounced in Bulgarian. None of us has any education in phonetics. So while I have found out that it is pronounced as `the close-mid back unrounded vowel ɤ` when stressed and `ɐ` when not stressed, this doesn't mean anything to him.

Comment: (Comment left before the edit:) This is off-topic here, please support the [Linguistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics) proposal. Thanks.

Comment: This is off-topic for EL&U, but a practical answer is to go find an audio clip that has the pronunciation and link it.

Comment: Although this is an extremely interesting question, it's off topic I guess. Anyway, are you asking about the твёрдый знак?

Comment: I just re-read the faq. I suppose it is off-topic because of the "no other languages" rules. Does that mean that if I had asked "are there English words which include the ɤ sound" without providing details, it would have been on-topic? Because that's what my question boils down to. With the info I gave, you only need knowledge of the IPA to answer it, not knowledge of Bulgarian.

Comment: @Alenanno, it is the same letter, but it isn't pronounced the same way as in Russian. We call it "Er golyam" in Bulgarian.

Comment: @rumtscho: actually it's off topic because it's more related to Linguistics, but if you can fix it in order to include English more, it will become on topic.

Comment: Thank you all, I edited it in a way which focuses more on the English language. Other suggestions for improvement are welcome.

Comment: I think that, no matter how you reword this, the thrust of the question is not about English. You can say "What's an English word that most closely approximates sound X in language Y?"...it's still not _about_ English. Too much knowledge of language Y is needed.

Comment: Still a fascinating question, for which there should be an outlet (commit to [Linguistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics) as Reg mentioned).

Comment: I am not sure I will support the Linguistics, just because I don't think I can come up with 10 good questions in 3 months (and certainly not 10 answers). But thank you for all for your help and suggestions, and also for leaving the question open long enough for Kosmonaut to give his good answer, he deserves the rep :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are no words in English that have the vowel [ɤ] in them.  The [ʌ] sound, like in "duck", is similar to [ɤ], but the sound is made in a slightly different place in the mouth. Generally, it is very difficult to instruct someone to articulate a vowel in a nearby, but unfamiliar, location in the mouth.  Instead, it is better to look at a different English vowel that only differs from [ɤ] in a way that is easy for someone to perceive and articulate.  For example, rounding of the lips is something that is easy for anyone to manipulate.

Aside from [ʌ], the vowel [ɤ] is also similar to the English vowel [o]; [o] is the close-mid back **rounded** vowel (while [ɤ] is close-mid back unrounded). This means that the only difference between [ɤ] and [o] is that for [o] the lips are rounded, and for [ɤ] the lips are unrounded (note the lips are also unrounded for e.g. English vowels [i] and [e]).

So, to pronounce [ɤ], I would instruct an English speaker to position their lips as if they are about to say [i] ("ee" sound), and then, without moving the lips, attempt to make an [o] sound.